# curl -sIX HEAD binary file

Tags: bash, curl, couchdb

```
#!/bin/bash

HEAD=`curl -sIX HEAD http://gert.iriscouch.com/www/test`
echo "$HEAD"
if [[ $HEAD =~ Etag:\ \"(.*)\" ]]; then
 echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
fi

HEAD=`curl -sIX HEAD http://gert.iriscouch.com/www/test/user.png`
echo "$HEAD"
if [[ $HEAD =~ Etag:\ \"(.*)\" ]]; then
 echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
fi
```

On the second HEAD it does not match the Etag?

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: CouchDB/1.1.0 (Erlang OTP/R14B03)
Etag: "2-bd7278b9cc8b0ddaf7c863102f42f246"
Date: Thu, 01 Sep 2011 19:47:02 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 207
Cache-Control: must-revalidate

2-bd7278b9cc8b0ddaf7c863102f42f246

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: CouchDB/1.1.0 (Erlang OTP/R14B03)
ETag: "2-bd7278b9cc8b0ddaf7c863102f42f246"
Date: Thu, 01 Sep 2011 19:47:03 GMT
Content-Type: image/png
Content-MD5: SS+3YnbRbRQ4uiJKcnFkdA==
Content-Length: 4003
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Comment: btw, -I implies a HEAD request so "-X HEAD" is superfluous there...

Comment: ok thanks, going to change that too in my code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case is different.

```
if [[ $HEAD =~ Etag:\ \"(.*)\" ]]; then


Etag: "2-bd7278b9cc8b0ddaf7c863102f42f246"

ETag: "2-bd7278b9cc8b0ddaf7c863102f42f246"
```

use

```
if [[ $HEAD =~ [Ee][Tt][Aa][Gg]:\ \"(.*)\" ]]; then
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Hard to see how this would be classified as a feature ;-) ...  Good luck and thanks for the reps.

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2

> Field names are case-insensitive.

The bug is in your code, 'ETAG', 'etag', 'ETag' and 'Etag' are all equally valid expressions of the header value.

However, I have changed CouchDB in the next release (1.2) to consistently use 'ETag' on the 'be strict in what you send' principle.